# Reason for a fragment to not show up

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

so I know there are a few topics around here that ask about this but none seemed to be the cause of my issue.  I have an ActionBarActivity that is going to be switching between a few different fragments, but I'm having a problem getting one of the fragments to show up.  The activity does show a fragment when it is first loaded and does that fine.  Here is the code that is setting up the initial fragment with the method to switch between fragments that I'm using.

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_container);
    final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setTitle("");
    if (savedInstanceState == null) navigateTo(START_SCREEN);
}

 public void navigateTo(int sectionNumber, Serializable objectParam) {
    Fragment fragment = null;
     switch (sectionNumber) {
           case START_SCREEN:
            fragment = createStartScreenFragment(); //returns an instance of the class for this fragment
            break;
        case SCREEN_TWO:
            fragment = createSecondScreenFragment(); //returns an instance of the class for this fragment
            break;
     }
    if (fragment == null) return;
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction trans = fm.beginTransaction();
    trans.add(R.id.activity_container, fragment, fragment.getTag());
    trans.commit();
    trans.show(fragment);
}
```

activity_containers.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical" android:id="@+id/activity_container"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

</FrameLayout>
```

The first fragment that loads successfuly

```
<GridLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_start_screen"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.android.Activity">    
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        />
 ...
</GridLayout>
```

And here is the fragment xml that isn't showing up

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/section_label" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:fadingEdge="vertical"
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
    android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
    android:padding="2dp">
</ListView>
```

And here is the misbehaving fragments relevant code:

```
public class SecondFragment extends Fragment {
    public final static int SECTION_NUMBER = 1;
    private String mTag = "TAG";
    private ParentActivity parentActivity;

    public SecondFragment() {

    }
    public static fragment  newInstance() {
        SecondFragment fragment = new SecondFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(final Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        parentActivity = (ParentActivity) getActivity();
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_second_fragment, container, false);
        ListView list = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);

        return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

The biggest problem I'm having here is that there is no error message shown.  The text view in the first fragment is supposed to trigger the second fragment to show up on the screen. This used to work when I had that fragment as a DialogFragment and just called .show() on an instance of it.  I need it to be a regular fragment now and it doesn't show up.  There's no error message that I can see, though debugging it does show it running through all of my code successfully and it looks like its properly inflating the view.

So what could I be missing here that is preventing the fragment from displaying?

Comment: you should return `rootView` instead of the `super.onCreateView`

Comment: Also, the xml for the fragment that isn't showing up doesn't seem to have a single root viewgroup?

Comment: Thank you so much Blackbelt, that was it.  You saved me from banging my head on the desk for the next 5 hours trying to figure that one out.  If you submit it as an answer, I'll mark it as the correct answer and close this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your layout

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/section_label" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:fadingEdge="vertical"
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
    android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
    android:padding="2dp">
</ListView>
```

Should be within a ViewGroup

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
  <TextView android:id="@+id/section_label" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
  <ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:fadingEdge="vertical"
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
    android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
    android:padding="2dp">
  </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

And you should return `rootView` in `onCreateView()`.

Also, you might need to use `replace` method of Fragment Manager to replace one fragment with another, instead of `add`.